# Calculating average interest rate with intermittent deposits

Tags: calculation, interest-rate, compound-interest, crowdfunding

I invest in a few medium to low risk accounts online (peer to peer loans and buy to let property crowdfunding).

I make regular deposits into these accounts, usually when the monthly salary comes in, but the time period between my deposits and the amount changes.

I know how to work out the effective APR from interest earned on a single deposit over a time span, for example, taking C (capital deposit), P (profit from interest), and T (time span in days) it would be:

APR = ((P/C + 1)^(365 / T) - 1) * 100

But if I then extend this to be over two time periods, taking:
C1 and C2 (starting amounts), T1 and T2 (timespans in days), P (total interest earned), and I (daily interest rate for simplicity)

P = (C1 * (I^T1 - 1)) + (C2 * (I^T2 - 1))

Is there a direct method to get the average interest rate (I) over the two periods, knowing all other variables?

I have attempted to create an iterative formula by rearranging to get one of the I's on one side:

I = (((P - C2 * (I^T2 - 1)) / C1) + 1) ^ (1/T1)

Taking the initial value of I as 1. But this equation diverges when I try to iterate it.

Is there either an iterative approach which converges or a direct approach?

(Money stack exchange does not have MathJax so I will repost these formulae as images once I have enough rep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to do this in my own program rather than having to use a 3rd party application such as Excel.
In the end the approach I found was best was the following:

1. Set variable *TooLow* to be an interest rate that is obviously too low, ie. zero.
2. Set variable *TooHigh* to be an interest rate that is obviously too high, ie. 10000% APR (assuming no payday loans here).
3. Set *Mid* = (*TooHigh* + *TooLow*) / 2.
4. Calculate how much interest you would have got assuming that the rate is *Mid*.
5. If the interest calculated is less than the actual interest you got then set *TooLow* = *Mid*, If  more then set *TooHigh* = *Mid*.
6. If you are not close enough then go to step 3 and repeat.

This method is a binary search algorithm and therefore is quite fast. It doesn't take many iterations to get accurate to a few decimal places.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly I think the easiest solution would be to use the XIRR formula in Excel. You can have a column of dates, and a column of cash flows, and it will calculate the rate for you.

*Description*

*Returns the internal rate of return for a schedule of cash flows that is not necessarily periodic. To calculate the internal rate of return for a series of periodic cash flows, use the IRR function.*

https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/XIRR-function-de1242ec-6477-445b-b11b-a303ad9adc9d

Comment: Yes, that's what I use to calculate my effective annual return: guzintas + dates,  guzoutas + dates, and the current value + today's date.